# Modify this jQuery accordion plugin so first tab is open on load

Tags: jquery

I'm using some code I found for a jQuery accordion because I don't like the animation from the jQueryUI accordion. However one thing I would like is to have the first tab open automatically on load. Everything else about it is great, if anyone has any insight, I would appreciate it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.accordion .item .heading').click(function() {
  
    var a = $(this).closest('.item');
    var b = $(a).hasClass('open');
 var c = $(a).closest('.accordion').find('.open');
  
 if(b != true) {
  $(c).find('.content').slideUp(200);
  $(c).removeClass('open');
 }

 $(a).toggleClass('open');
 $(a).find('.content').slideToggle(200);

 });
});
```

```css
.accordion {
   width: 100%;
   border-radius: 5px;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
   left: 2em;
}
.accordion .item .heading {
   height: 50px;
   line-height: 50px;
   font-size: 17px;
   cursor: pointer;
   color: #fff;
   padding-left: 15px;
   background: #ee6363 url('arrow.png') no-repeat;
   background-position: right 20px top -95px;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #ec8484;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
.accordion .item.open .heading, .accordion .item:last-child .heading { 
 border: 0; 
}
.accordion .item.open .heading {
  background-position: right 20px top -5px; 
}
.accordion .item .content {
   display: none;
   padding: 15px;
   background: #fff;
   font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <div class="accordion">
      <div class="item">
         <div class="heading">This is the first heading</div>
         <div class="content">This is the first content</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
         <div class="heading">This is the second heading</div>
         <div class="content">This is the second content</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
         <div class="heading">This is the third title</div>
         <div class="content">This is the third content</div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just trigger a click on the first on pageload ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.accordion .item .heading').click(function() {
  
    var a = $(this).closest('.item');
    var b = $(a).hasClass('open');
 var c = $(a).closest('.accordion').find('.open');
  
 if(b != true) {
  $(c).find('.content').slideUp(200);
  $(c).removeClass('open');
 }

 $(a).toggleClass('open');
 $(a).find('.content').slideToggle(200);

 }).first().trigger('click');
})
```

```css
.accordion {
   width: 100%;
   border-radius: 5px;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
   left: 2em;
}
.accordion .item .heading {
   height: 50px;
   line-height: 50px;
   font-size: 17px;
   cursor: pointer;
   color: #fff;
   padding-left: 15px;
   background: #ee6363 url('arrow.png') no-repeat;
   background-position: right 20px top -95px;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #ec8484;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
.accordion .item.open .heading, .accordion .item:last-child .heading { 
 border: 0; 
}
.accordion .item.open .heading {
  background-position: right 20px top -5px; 
}
.accordion .item .content {
   display: none;
   padding: 15px;
   background: #fff;
   font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <div class="accordion">
      <div class="item">
         <div class="heading">This is the first heading</div>
         <div class="content">This is the first content</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
         <div class="heading">This is the second heading</div>
         <div class="content">This is the second content</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
         <div class="heading">This is the third title</div>
         <div class="content">This is the third content</div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the end of your document.ready function,

```
$('.accordion .item .heading').eq(0).click();
```

or

```
$('.accordion .item .heading').first().click();
```

or

```
$('.accordion .item .heading:first').click();
```